# How to use FireUnit to test my web page?

Tags: unit-testing, firefox

Can someone please tell me how can i test my web page in FireUnit?
http://ejohn.org/blog/fireunit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just played around with it last week and wrote a few test cases. You'll want to create a test case file and include it as part of your page. (perhaps use a conditional like "debug=true" to 
prevent inclusion during production)

I found the .Compare method to be the most useful. You can write stuff like:

```
fireunit.compare(
  "expected result",
  callToFunction2(), // tested
  "This is the test name"
);
```

Note that since you are comparing strings here, if you want to do JSON instead, you'll have to JSON.stringify the output first.

Upon running the page with the included js file, you'll see test results under the "Test" panel of firebug. (assuming you have the extension installed)

Comment: As i am naive to FireUnit, can you please tell me after inclduing the js file, it will directly execute the file or do we need to do anything extra?

Comment: Yes, by including the .js file on the page, FireUnit will automatically execute the tests. You should see the results in the FireUnit tab.